# Onclick and show content in <div> using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have using JSON to retrieve data :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var url = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "Products/GetMenuList";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, dataOption) {

            $("#navmenu-v").append("<li><a href='javascript:DoNothing();' id='list'>" 
            + dataOption.Name + "</a></li>");
        });
        $('#list').click(function () {
            //add some content to div
        });
    });

});
```

I want to click on the #list, and then do any thing. But when I test with alert, it only works in the first list.

Can anyone tell me, how could I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: want to display data in div tag on click event ..???

Comment: @LaxmanRana : Yes, on click event on a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select more than one elements by id you should use a better selector:

```
    $('a#list').click(function () {
        //add some content to div
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourdivid').html('whateveryouwant');
```

Comment: when I do that, it only works on the first <li>, the others not work.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on ubercooluk's answer:

You'll want to wrap that in a click event handler.

```
$('#yourdivid').click(function() {  $('#yourdivid').html('whateveryouwant');  });
```

EDIT: Try using query find to reference the added elements by their id or class. 
http://api.jquery.com/find/

Like this:

```
$('#yourdivid').click(function() { $('#yourdivid').find('.li-class or something that references these').html('whateveryouwant'); });
```

Additionally, never use an id more than once. Use a class and then use the find method described above.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

since the elements are created dynamically after the document is loaded, normal click handler will not work. you have to delegate the handler, make use of [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). 
use `href='javascript:void(0);'` to prevent default

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "Products/GetMenuList";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, dataOption) {

            $("#navmenu-v").append("<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='list'>" 
            + dataOption.Name + "</a></li>");
        });
    });
   $('#navmenu-v').on('click','#list',function () {
      $('#mydiv').append('new code');
   });
});
```

Comment: then make use of delegate, on is from version 1.7